# Detect selecting same node on treeView C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a problem with detecting clicking event on previous selected node, here is the method, but I detects only when node is changed, so does anyone knows how to solve this?

Actually I want to detect every time when node is selected, no matter if that node was previous selected or not, because I open new form window every time on click.

```
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e){
            Console.WriteLine("Selected node is->" + e.Node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`TreeView.AfterSelect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.afterselect?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) event - as the name suggests - fires only when a different node is selected. It doesn't fire again when you mouse-click on the same node because it is already selected. If you need to get notified when a selected node is clicked, then handle also a mouse event like [`TreeView.NodeMouseClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) or [`Control.MouseClick`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.mouseclick?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.MouseClick)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) with the [`TreeView.HitTest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.hittest?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TreeView.HitTest)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) method.

So, you already have the `AfterSelect` event, keep it to detect nodes selection by keyboard keys.

```cs
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    // Call x method or routine...
}
```

Handle the `TreeView.NodeMouseClick` event to execute the same routine **if** the clicked node is the `SelectedNode`. Otherwise leave it to the `AfterSelect` event.

```cs
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node == treeView1.SelectedNode)
        // Call same x method or routine...
}
```

Or handle the `MouseClick` event instead to get the clicked node even if you click on the other predefined areas of the `TreeNode`. See [`TreeViewHitTestInfo.Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeviewhittestinfo.location?view=netframework-4.8&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.TreeViewHitTestInfo.Location)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%2CVersion%253Dv4.8)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) property.

```cs
private void treeView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var ht = treeView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (ht.Node != null)
    {
        if (e.Node == treeView1.SelectedNode)
            // Call same x method or routine...
        else
            treeView1.SelectedNode = ht.Node;
    }
}
```